# JDO query a list using a list

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I am using JDO to query my database.  The entity class looks kind of like this:

```
class Entity
{
  // other members of the class
  List<String> stuff;

  // members and methods
}
```

I am writing a web service against a standardized interface.  This interface allows a user to search for Entity objects based on a set of filters.  One of these being a List of possible stuff.  To try and be clearer, a user can provide a List of strings, we'll call it stuffQuery.  The user can ask the service to return all Entity objects where the stuff list contains at least one element from the stuffQuery list.  I cannot find a way in JDO to write this query.  Effectively it would be a return of all Entity object where the intersection of stuff and stuffQuery is not empty.

My only thought right now is to build a filter by basically looping through stuffQuery appending a series of stuff.contains(stuffQuery.get(idx)) filters OR'ed together to the filter string for the JDO query.  That's ugly.  I don't like it.  If there is a more elegant solution I would appreciate knowing it.

Environment: Java, Spring Framework, Datanucleus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar situation before. I didn't actually solve the problem but I queried my objects in a different way. I'd suggest looping over the string list to query your objects.